# Simulating Win+1 with multiple windows on autohotkey

Tags: windows, windows-10, autohotkey

I'm trying to bind the F keys, to coorespond to Win+1-5, to switch between windows.

I'm running into an issue, where if I have more then one window for an app, instead of switching to that app, like the original key would do, it would stay "focused" on the bar (It shows me a preview of the two windows, and I Can move around the apps with the arrow keys).

Here's the script I am using

```
F1:: Send, {LWin Down}{1 Down}{1 Up}{LWin Up}
F2:: Send, {LWin Down}{2 Down}{2 Up}{LWin Up}
F3:: Send, {LWin Down}{3 Down}{3 Up}{LWin Up}
F4:: Send, {LWin Down}{4 Down}{4 Up}{LWin Up}
F5:: Send, {LWin Down}{5 Down}{5 Up}{LWin Up}
```

I tried several variations, including seperating the up and down into 2 lines and putting `sleep 50` between them.

Answer (score 0):

On my Window 7 machine I had to change your lines like this,

`F1:: Send, {LWin Down}{1}{LWin Up}`

and it worked exactly as the built in function. Of course only the first window in the group will pop up but that's how the built in function works in Windows 7 at least.